# How do I set up row level security based upon relationship in another table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, best-practices

I'm working on a social media app with PostgreSQL where I need the following features:

- Users must be able to search for other users based upon their display names (display names are public)
- Users should not be able to see not connected users' email addresses
- Users with confirmed connections must be able to view the email address of any connected users.

Right now, the "protected" (not sure if that's the right word) is just limited to email addresses, but I can see in the future wanting to do something similar with other columns that might be added.

Here is how the tables are currently set up. I'm really not great at database administration, so I could have this all totally wrong.

Users

| table_schema | table_name | column_name | udt_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| public | users | id | uuid |
| public | users | email | text |
| public | users | display_name | text |
| public | users | last_post_published_at | timestamptz |

User connections

| table_schema | table_name | column_name | udt_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| public | user_connections | id | int8 |
| public | user_connections | created_at | timestamptz |
| public | user_connections | user_a_id | uuid |
| public | user_connections | user_b_id | uuid |
| public | user_connections | user_a_confirmed | bool |
| public | user_connections | user_b_confirmed | bool |

What's the best way to achieve the features and security set that I'm going for? Essentially what *thought* I needed was row level security based upon some sort of relationship established in a foreign key, but now I'm suspecting I need to look at it from a completely different angle.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out a way to do this. I don't have a lot of experience in this field, so there's probably better ways, but here it is.

The first is to set a policy that evaluates visibility based on presence of a matching row in user_connections for a given expression. The `USING` expression for the policy ended up looking like this:

```sql
(
    (uid() = id) OR 
    (
        ( SELECT count(*) AS count
            FROM user_connections
            WHERE (
                user_connections.user_a_confirmed AND
                user_connections.user_b_confirmed AND
                (
                    (user_connections.user_a_id = users.id) OR 
                    (user_connections.user_b_id = users.id)
                ) AND
                (
                    (user_connections.user_a_id = users.id) OR 
                    (user_connections.user_b_id = users.id)
                )
            )
        ) >= 1
    )
)
```

The second is to set up a publicly accessible view for users that filters down visible columns. I did this via:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW users_public AS
    SELECT id, display_name
    FROM users;
```

Comment: Try `EXISTS` instead of `(SELECT count(*) ...) >= 1`. And avoid `OR` if you can. Both will be good for performance.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a go. As far as avoiding `OR`, how would I accomplish this logic then? Would I create multiple policies? Or would something like `user.id in (user_connections.user_a_id, user_connections.user_b_id)` be what you're getting at?

Comment: I have no idea how to avoid `OR` either. I just wanted to point out that it may be a performance problem.